# Deleting a Partition

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition

Sometimes ago, I fully installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my hard drive. I was asked to upgrade to 17.10, and after I did this, I started experiencing certain difficulties. I couldn't fix these issues so I created a live CD, then installed 17.04 in another partition. I have been using this since then. The issue now is, I don't want the 17.10 partition anymore. I want to delete it, but this is dangerous as my grub is installed in it. How do I fix this issue? How do I safely delete and merge these partitions?

Comment: Is it really 17.04?   17.04 (2017.April release) is past EOL and is now off-topic on this site. 17.04 has no fixes for meltdown, spectre nor security updates that have occurred since it's EOL.  I'd suggest you moving to 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS which are supported.  If 17.04 was your last installed; it's likely it contains the grub that is being used; if not you only have to have it re-write your MBR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot into your 17.04 installation that you want to keep.
2. Run `lsblk` to figure out where everything is, and make mental / physical note of this for later
3. Run `fdisk /dev/sdX` where X is the appropriate letter associated with your drive, as you found in 2 (often /dev/sda)
4. Press `d` for delete.
5. When asked something along the lines of `Partition number 1,2, 5-7, default 7` it's asking what partition you would like to delete. You should have seen it when you ran `lsblk`. It will be something like /dev/sdxN, where x is the disk (often /dev/sda) and N is the number associated with the partition (something like /dev/sda2). Input the partition number, and press enter. The partition will be deleted.
6. Type `w`and press enter to write changes and quit.
7. Reinstall grub. This is done with `grub-install`. Run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdxN` where sdxN is the identifier for the partition you're keeping. This will install grub to that partition. Alternatively, you can do `sudo grub-install /dev/sdx` where x is replaced with the disk (often /dev/sda), that way your grub installation will be partition independent and you can avoid this in the future.
8. Hold your breath and reboot. You should be presented with grub again and be able to boot into your new system.

Before you do all of this, I suggest you make a live usb just in case something goes wrong and you can't boot, so you'll have a way to chroot back in and fix things. Also back up your important data, etc (just in case). Last, after all of this is done, you will need to be able to boot into a live environment anyway, and expand your new main partition to fill the rest of the new empty space, if so desired. This is easily accomplished with something like gparted.

Comment: When I typed `w` to write, I got `Re-reading the partition table failed.: Device or resource busy`

Comment: Nothing is happening at the end.